# How to have delay in animation with display: none and opacity: 0 without JavaScript

Tags: javascript, css-animations

I want to have a delay in transition of an element. When I use display none and make it display: block there's no delay in transition.

When I use opacity: 0 my layout is ruined since the text is occupying space.

I want to use both at the same time, like display: none to display: bock, wait, then opacity: 0 to opacity: 1.

How do we achive this without javascript?

```
.card p {
    line-height: 2rem;
    display: none;
    opacity: 0;
    font-size: 1.2rem;
}
```

```
.card.active p {
    transition-delay: 500ms;
    transition: 1700ms opacity ease-in-out;
    display: block;
    opacity: 1; 
}
```

This doesn't work as stated above.

Comment: You'll need to use an animation for that

Comment: You can see an example here: https://jsfiddle.net/szwj0nyc/

Comment: @JoãoPauloMacedo thanks mate, I didn't have to add any additional JS and it worked for me.